# Merge release branch to master while excluding CI entries

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a branch, say `release-branch` with:

- Some of the commits from master (since the branch was forked) already merged
- Lots of **log spam** in the form of maven-release-plugin updates due to Jenkins

I tried `git pull --rebase -X theirs upstream release-branch` (from a fresh local copy of `upstream/master`)

With this, a large amount of commits are the Maven release plugin working on POM versioning, which I don't need at all (the plugin has already updated POM files on master anyway).

How can I merge all the changes from branch into master, while excluding those from jenkins (I guess that means skipping all from a particular user or with specified name format)

Comment: Note that my merge strategy is probably wrong too, haven't tried other combinations yet.